airflow 2.9 schedule DAG on the first weekday day of the month every month
I would like to schedule a DAG on the first weekday of the month for every month. So for example this years it would have been scheduled at:
2024-01-01
2024-02-01
2024-03-01
2024-04-01
2024-05-01
2024-06-03  -----> here the third because the first is a Saturday

I have had a look at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/timetable.html , but it seems quite complex to structure such DAG. Is this the only way to go for that kind scheduling ?
This is my logic to find the first working day:
import pendulum
year = 2024

for month in range(0,13):
    first_day_month = pendulum.DateTime(year=year,month=month,day=1)
    working_day = first_day_month if first_date_month.weekday() >= 0 and first_day_month.weekday <= 4 else first_day_month.next(pendulum.MONDAY)
    print(working_day)


from datetime import datetime

import pendulum

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin import LoggingMixin


@task.short_circuit(task_id="check-date")
def check_date(data_interval_end: datetime):
    logger = LoggingMixin().log
    year = data_interval_end.year
    month = data_interval_end.month

    # logic to find the first working day
    first_day_month = pendulum.datetime(year, month, 1)
    working_day = (
        first_day_month
        if first_day_month.weekday() <= 4
        else first_day_month.next(pendulum.MONDAY)
    )

    logger.info(f"Checking if {data_interval_end.date()} equals {working_day.date()}")
    return data_interval_end.date() == working_day.date()


with DAG(
    dag_id="check-working-day",
    schedule_interval="0 0 1-7 * *",
    start_date=datetime(2024, 1, 1),
    catchup=True,
) as dag:
    start = EmptyOperator(task_id="start_task")
    continue_task = EmptyOperator(task_id="continue_task")

    start >> check_date() >> continue_task

It can be used instead of scheduling using ShortCircuitOperator.
This function acts as a ShortCircuitOperator by determining whether the subsequent tasks should execute based on the date check. The function check_date determines the first weekday of the current month. If the first day of the month is a weekend (Saturday or Sunday), it calculates the next Monday. The task will short-circuit (i.e., prevent downstream tasks from executing) if the execution date does not match this first weekday.
